# Rename tag "Flags" to "Flag" (or create a synonym), or create a new "Flag"-tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The existing tag **Wiki** for the [flags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flags)-flag refers to the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) (without **s**) module. While the existing tag **Excerpt** for this tag seems to not really correspond to that. For more details, refer to these (recently rejected) tag edit suggestions, in which I at first was trying to make it all related to the 'Flag' module:

- [Tag Wiki excerpt](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/59801).
- [Tag Wiki](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/59800).

Even though I can perfectly understand (now) the rejection reason, it appears to me as at least "not consistent", and something should be done to fix this (popular) tag.

---

It seems there are possibly 3 approaches (at least, maybe there are others ...):

1. Create a new tag 'Flag', dedicated to the Flag module, and leave the 'Flags' tag as is (probably with a corrected tag wiki+excerpt to clarify the difference between both tags). Together with this, perform a mass retag operation from questions currently flagged with "Flags" to "Flag" (i.e. any question that is specific to the "flag" module).
2. Create a new tag 'flag', together with marking 'flags' as a synonym.
3. A moderator simply renames that tag from 'flags' to 'flag'.

Either approach could work for me, though "***I'd vote for option 1***".

Answer (score 1):

Flags are items created using flag module. I see absolutely no reason to bother with rename, but two reasons not to:

1. Current form was OK for many people over years, with only one vote against.
2. Flags raised are the point of importance. Not the module behind them.

Answer (score 1):

[flags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flags) was created on October 2012, and it was never used to refer explicitly to the Flag module, as the existing questions evidence. There are many modules handling flags that I don't see any reason to privilege one over all the existing ones.

As for creating [flag](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flag), on Stack Exchange we don't use two tags that differ just for the singular/plural form; they would just confuse the users, who would just pick-up one random. Misuse of a tag is the reason why some tags have been replaced with a different tag.